# No shader cache on Mesa 17.3. with Intel graphics

Tags: 16.04, graphics, games, mesa

For long, most games on Intel video cards ran badly because of driver compilation in the middle of game, which caused extreme frame drops. Mesa 17.1 and above should have a feature that caches the compiled shaders. According to information I could google up, the shaders are stored in `.cache/mesa` and that it really speeds up games.

So I installed it from a backport, but the `.cache/mesa/` folder did not appear and games behaved as if there was no shader cache. I compiled it from source (version 1.17.3), used `glxinfo` to check that it's really there, but it seemed correct. I have tried more games, but no evidence of caching of shaders appeared. My friend using it on Fedora ran Lightsmark and his `.cache/mesa` folder was filled with compiled shaders. When I did it, nothing happened.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. This is `glxinfo`'s information on this:

```
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)  (0x5916)
Version: 17.3.0
Accelerated: yes
Video memory: 3072MB
Unified memory: yes
Preferred profile: core (0x1)
Max core profile version: 4.5
Max compat profile version: 3.0
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.3.0-devel (git-8e9e339c53)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature was made available for AMD cards, but it was postponed for Intel cards.

Since posting this, it has been posted for review (the review version did not work for me for some reasons) and accepted into the main branch. It's now available as a part of the working version of Mesa 1.17.4. (on github, so in needs to be manually compiled). It needs to be activated by setting the environment variable `MESA_GLSL_CACHE_DISABLED=0` (because as a testing feature, it's disabled by default).

Now it creates a `mesa` folder in `.cache` and video games are faster.

Answer (score 1):

Mesa **17.3.0** driver doesn't store shared cache on-disk for now.

See this patch to use shared cache on-disk.

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-dev/2017-October/173828.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I tried it, but it did not do anything - although by all accounts, it should.